# NullPointerException for OnClickerListener of Google Sign in buttons

Tags: android

I am getting this error with 2 of my buttons.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the code:

```
    btn_signin = findViewById(R.id.signin_btn);
    btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    btn_signout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signout_btn);
    btn_signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            btn_signin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btn_signout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            emailText.setText(" ".toString());
                            nameText.setText(" ".toString());
                        }
                    });
        }

    });
```

How can I solve this problem? Why is it working on every other button but not these two?

Edit: The buttons are in the header of navigation if that matters. Here is the relevant part from xml file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/signin_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signout_btn"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Sign Out"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Just double check if you're inflating correct layout.

Comment: That should be my problem because these buttons are in a different xml file. How can I make sure this code works for them?

Comment: Include them into layout you're inflating. You can use <include/> for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access these buttons you must first access the Navigation header:

```
View navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
btn_signin = (SignInButton) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.signin_btn);
```

`navigationView` is the `NavigationView` you must find in the your layout

Comment: Yes. But I am using Android Stuido's drawer activity and this buttons are in nav_header_main.xml

May be I should put all of the Google SignIn code into onNavigationItemSelected?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.

Can you breakdown the first line for me? For example can I use it more than once like this:

View navHeader2 = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

Comment: @AhmetB.Arpa of course you can, everywhere that navigationView is visible.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: If I wanted to move buttons from navigation header to navigation menu, how should I approach?

Comment: @AhmetB.Arpa The simplest way is to do it like this in the menu:  `<item
                android:id="@+id/itemname"                app:actionViewClass="Button"
                android:title="title" />`